# How to link html files together using Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

i am using django 3.0 with python 3.8. i am new to coding. below is my project hierarchy.i want to connect my "home" page to next html "teoco" page by clicking on continue button for which i have below html code

myproject.urls-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('training_review.urls')),
    path('teoco', include('training_review.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

home.urls-

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
    path('teoco',views.teoco, name='teoco')
]
```

home.views-

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def teoco(request):
    return render(request, 'teoco.html')
```

Comment: you can directly use `{% url 'teoco' %}` in href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Django's built-in URL tags. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name)
>   matching a given view and optional parameters. Any special characters
>   in the resulting path will be encoded using iri_to_uri().
>
> This is a way to output links without violating the DRY principle by
>   having to hard-code URLs in your templates:

`{% url 'some-url-name' v1 v2 %}`

So in your button have this set to the href attribute, for example:

```
<input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="New Line" onclick="location.href="{% url 'addrow' %}""  />
```

This above code will navigate to the views.py as defined in your urls and you can render any html page as you like in that method.

Comment: thanks for explaining do well. i tried putting below code but still showing ";" expected in the end of line..please help   <input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="window.location.href='{ % url 'teoco' % }';">

Comment: Can you try changing it to `<input type="button" value="Continue" onclick="window.location.href="{% url 'teoco' %}"" />`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked..now i want to do the reverse of it also..i mean i want to add abutton in my second "teoco" page something like "go to the home page". how do i add one more address to the base.htm and how to call it from "teoco" page.below is my base.html </head>
<body>
    <a href="{% url 'teoco' %}"> <input type="button" value="Continue" ></a>
    
    

    {% block content %}
    

    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

Comment: Great. If this has worked then please accept the answer( see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)) to state that the initial question has been resolved.

Comment: If you want to do the reverse of it then it would follow the same logic. Firstly, a button with the URL tag defined, and then in the urls.py redirect to a method that will render the html page(in this case, the homepage) . If you are new to Django do consider reading [this](https://realpython.com/django-redirects/). I found this really helpful when I first came across this problem

Answer (score 0):

you can create an HTML file like this:

`home.html`

```
<html>
<a href="/teaco" > Go to teaco page</a> or
<a href="{% url 'teoco' %}"> Go to teaco page </a>

</html>
```